# undo git merged pushes into wrong branch

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, github, merge

I was working on a branch and pushing it to a remote repository. But, I noticed later, I was using the wrong syntax:

```
git push origin my-branch:master
```

So instead of pushing to my-branch, I was pushing a merged version of the project to master repo (my-branch merged with master and pushed to master repo).

The thing is my master remains the same locally (right?), while master on github is some pushes ahead and all merged with my-branch.

How could I revert these changes to get master repo at the same stage as my local master? Or how can I get master repo at the same point it was before all this branch merging pushes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it simply by checking out master, and force-pushing (assuming your local `master` is set up to track `origin/master`):

```
git checkout master
git push -f
```

You could do it a little more safely by being explicit:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```